# Assigning roles in Sitecore to items pulled in via the Sharepoint connector

Tags: sharepoint, sitecore, sitecore6

We have a Sitecore 6.2 site, which uses the SharePoint connector to pull in items into the Sitecore document library. As per the standard approach, the SharePoint items find their way into the Sitecore document library via a proxy item to the approproate SharePoint media connection.

My question is: can we assign Sitecore roles to the items pulled in from SharePoint?

I've tried using the Security Editor to assign roles to the SharePoint items, however the roles don't seem to "stay on", which I'm guessing means that Sitecore is internally failing to assign the role.

We need to use roles so that we can implement secure download areas.

Any ideas folks?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can assign security directly on items, but it should be possible to do this on template standard values. So, try switching to "sharepoint" database, browse for any template you use for the items from SharePoint and assign the security on standard values.

If this works, you might want to create an extra hierarchy of templates in order just to have different security settings on different items.